# awk string substr and cut not need char

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to delete some char on string, example I have this string

```
$ tst=/oracle/orcl/dbms1911c
$ printf '%s' ${tst} | awk -F'/' '{print substr($4,5,6)}'
$1911c
```

How can I remove the `11` and my output will be `19c`? I want only this when the string is not 19c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like a job for sed, rather than awk. then it would be something like, cat file | sed 's/11//g';

Comment: @john-jones thanks, didn't remember the sed, but in this case is 11 but could be something else. Could be another thing I only want two firsts char and the c on final

Comment: then s/19.*c$/19c/g;

Comment: @john-jones thanks again :) forgot to say, but if is other number, I will want the two first character and c on final

Comment: you can figure it out just study some sed en regular expressions.

Comment: wrt `${tst}` - the `{` and `}` are doing nothing at all in that statement but it's missing the quotes `"` that it requires to stop it breaking in various ways for various values of `tst`. It should be `"$tst"`. not `${tst}` or you can write `"${tst}"` if you like how the curly brackets look. It's extremely important that you understand https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for writing any shell scripts.

Comment: Also, when you do `printf '%s'` instead of `printf '%s\n'` the output is not a valid text line since it's missing a terminating newline and so YMMV with what any tool you pipe it to does with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

***1st solution:*** Create a variable with `substr` of `awk` and then play with it to get exactly needed shown value, this approach will be useful in case we need to use this variable for further in the program too. Where `tst=/oracle/orcl/dbms1911c` is the variable's value as per shown samples.

```
printf '%s' ${tst} | 
awk -F'/' '{val=substr($4,5,6);print substr(val,1,2) substr(val,5)}'
```

**2nd solution:** Without using a variable and using `substr` itself, though I feel 1st approach is BEST that variable could be used for other tasks also, for fun and as an another option adding this one.

```
printf '%s' ${tst} | 
awk -F'/' '{print substr(substr($4,5,6),1,2) substr(substr($4,5,6),5)}'
```

***3rd solution:*** or try this substr also here like:

```
printf '%s' ${tst} | 
awk -F'/' '{print substr($4,5,2) substr($4,9)}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used in the past but I don't remember how I made. the 1st solution for me looks good.

Comment: @scapy, or we could use like, `printf '%s' ${tst} | awk -F'/' '{print substr($4,5,2) substr($4,9)}'` too here, cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$tst" | sed 's/.*\(..\)..\(.\)$/\1\2/'
19c
```